# Call different svg files with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have map1.svg and map2.svg.

On index.php I have some options to select. If you select option 1 you see map 1, if you select option 2 you see map 2. I was doing it with php, but I'm not sure how to do it onclick (I am aware I am mixing js with php here and I shouldn't). I wanted to do something like:

```
<ul> 
<li><a id="one" onclick="<?php $option=1?>">Option One</a></li> 
<li><a id="two" onclick="<?php $option=2?>">Option Two</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
 <?php if ($option == 1) {
            include("map1.svg"); 
       } elseif ($option ==2) {
            include("map2.svg");
    } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: There's not enough code here to give a proper answer.  Basically, you will want to modify an img src element ... where are you placing the image in HTML?

Comment: I don't want to change any image. I just want to import the maps according to the option I clicked.

Comment: What is `include("map1.svg");` a function? Does it even works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul> 
   <li><a onclick="showMap('map_one')">Option One</a></li> 
   <li><a onclick="showMap('map_two')">Option Two</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="map_one" style="display:none">PHP include map 1 here</div>
<div id="map_two" style="display:none">PHP include map 2 here</div>
```

after you included whatever you want the way you want inside the hidden `#map_` elements:

```
function showMap(mapID) {
   var mapTarget = document.getElementById( mapID );
   mapTarget.style.display = "block";
}
```

```js
function  showMap(mapID) {
  var mapTarget = document.getElementById( mapID );
  mapTarget.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<ul> 
  <li><a onclick="showMap('map_one')">Option One</a></li> 
  <li><a onclick="showMap('map_two')">Option Two</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="map_one" style="display:none">PHP include map 1 here</div>
<div id="map_two" style="display:none">PHP include map 2 here</div>
```